# Building history of storm worker assignments

Tags: apache-storm

I want to build a centralised history that looks like

```
timestamp : topology_name : component_name : topology_id : component_id : VM hostname : VM IP : Worker port
```

What would be the best to go about it in Storm? I can think of

1. Reporting this from prepare() method of a spout/bolt
2. Write a custom scheduler that reports the assignments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reporting this from prepare() method of a spout/bolt

This requires you to enforce a certain type of spout and bolt and you need to account for subclasses which don't call `super.prepare`, e.g. by making `prepare` `final` and make it call `protected abstract prepare0` to enforce subclass logic there.

> Write a custom scheduler that reports the assignments

That's what I'd do since it's more transparent for the spout and bolt registration and can be reused without any restrictions and incompatibilites. It's probably more complex and requires more insight into Storm internals.